# Uploading a file - DocumentList.java sample giving 'Authorization required' error

Tags: java, file-upload, google-api

I am trying to upload a file from my desktop to google drive. I gave the `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` in the `DocumentList.java` sample given by Google. When I run as java application, I am getting below error at:

`return service.insert(buildUrl(URL_DEFAULT + URL_DOCLIST_FEED), newDocument);`

Code:

```
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CLIENT_ID);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);    
oauthParameters.setScope("https://docs.google.com/feeds/");
DocsService service = new DocsService("wise");
```

Error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Authorization required
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:400)
    at com.DocumentList.uploadFile(DocumentList.java:538)
    at com.DocumentList.login(DocumentList.java:230)
    at com.DocumentList.main(DocumentList.java:546)
```